# Connect to Sharepoint-Site directly in Office

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ms-office

For some reasons I want to open and edit some documents on a sharepoint site directly in Office (Excel) and not open it from IE. How can i do this? Is this possible? In other words can I directly open (checkout and edit) in Excel a file in a sharepoint-folder?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean just open document in Word form SharePoint, so that Word will save all changes back when you click save button? There is such functionality by default. Just click to open context menu of item and chose Edit in Microsoft Word.